# Custom File Upload - Removed file input field

Tags: jquery, html, forms, file-upload

Problems with Custom File Upload - from here http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/fEdrz

Using this code successfully replaces the FILE Browser button and styles the upload as expected.
The problem is that when using it the code seems to remove the INPUT field and when submitting the form the `$_FILES` array is empty?

1. Form is correctly encoded (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`)
2. Id's return a value when using 'browse' and selecting an image from my local file system (e.g. `$('#imageLogo').val()` returns file name )
3. when not using the JS wrapper the file input is passed correctly.

Generated code by using

```
<script>$('input[type=file]').customFile();</script>


<div class="custom-file-upload">
    <div class="file-upload-wrapper">
       <input type="file" name="logo_file" id="logoImage" class="custom-file-upload-hidden" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
        <input type="text" class="file-upload-input" title="a68a4029222401.55e8249a99c6b.jpg">
         <button type="button" class="file-upload-button" tabindex="-1">Select a File</button>
       </div>
   </div>
```

On submission of the form the file element is not available? (`$_FILES`) Output post submission.

```
array (size=0)
```

empty

Therefore, it seems that the code is being replaced/removed and the form then does not know about the file element (even though I can access the original

When I remove the JS call to run this (`//$('input[type=file]').customFile();`) the file now appears correctly when submitting the form...?
Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My apologise for this but the solution came in the form of formatting the HTML correctly. 
After running it through a W3C validator is showed that the containing divs and the form was nested incorrectly.
So my assumption is that since the JS creates a new input field and the original is replaced, since the divs in the page ended after the form the new element was somehow push outside the

```
<form></form>
```

and not submitted.
There is probably a more technical way to write this using DOM lanuage but basically the problem was well (or unwell) formatted HTML.

No PHP nessasary here and the field was not being submitted in the first place.
Thanks anyway Chetan.